# How to show myapp on AirDrop? Whats wrong in my Plist file?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying  to list my app on Air drop . Like You are on Photo Gallery and hit share . Airdrop will open where i want to show my app .. currently my app is not showing  on Air Drop. I am, trying to allow all types of files

Here is info.plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.apache.cordova.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>XPC!</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
     <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Unknown File</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.calendar-event</string>
            <string>public.database</string>
            <string>public.executable</string>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.content </string>
            <string>public.item</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Video</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.video</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>  
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve has nothing to do with AirDrop. AirDrop is a feature to share files between devices over Bluetooth or Wifi.

In your case, you want to register your app to be able to open some kind of files.
You should take a look at [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781290/598812) from [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson).

For your plist file, I think that you forgot to declare the icon file that needs to be used.
Example from the previous link:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Document-molecules-320.png</string>
            <string>Document-molecules-64.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Molecules Structure File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.sunsetlakesoftware.molecules.pdb</string>
            <string>org.gnu.gnu-zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.plain-text</string>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Molecules Structure File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.sunsetlakesoftware.molecules.pdb</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>pdb</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>chemical/x-pdb</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Now i got 

Error ITMS-90362 — Share Extension